# avformat_write_header() changes my stream's time_base

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, frame-rate, libavformat

I have a high framerate camera which can capture >2000 fps. My plan was to assign actual capture timestamps with µs resolution to the frames and encode with H.264 in a matroska file.

So I set the `time_base` of both the `AVStream` and the `AVCodecContext` to `{1, 1'000'000}`. But after calling `avformat_write_header(avFormatContext, nullptr)` I notice that the stream's `time_base` is `{1, 1'000}`. Now, since my framerate is double this resolution, I get identical consecutive timestamps and half my frames get lost when I extract them from the video file.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and what I can do about it? Preferably in a way that preserves the correct timestamps.

Comment: Is the language you are working in for this application `C` or `C++`?  (should include only one of these tags to reflect what you are using)

Comment: You could also attempt to force a higher time_base using FFmpegs commandline tool and see if it works. If that is successful you can apply similar changes to your code using the FFmpeg libraries

Comment: @ryyker, I'm using C++. Thought the ffmpeg interfaces are in C.

Comment: ffmpeg sets a fixed timebase for Matroska. Use mp4.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan! It didn't occur to me that the file format has an opinion on time resolution. MP4 fixed it.